# Google Sheets - countif with dynamic range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In `sheet1` have a column with a list of IDs, each with a set of statuses:

```
ID  Apr   May      Jun
1   Load  Load     Complete
2   Load  Complete NA
3   Load  Load     Load
```

In a separate sheet, `sheet2` I have a list of the IDs and I am trying to show which of those are complete. My thinking is to use `countif` with a dynamic cell range using the `address` function:

```
=countif("'sheet1'!"&address(row(index('sheet1'!$A$1:$A$5,match(A2,'sheet1'!$A$1:$A$5,0),1)),3)&":"&ADDRESS(row(index('sheet1'!$A$1:$A$5,match(A5,'sheet1'!$A$1:$A$500,0),1))+1,26),"Completed")
```

This formula should find the relevant row for each Id and then check to see whether there are any values of 'Completed' in that row. When combined with an `if` function, this should give an output of the following in `sheet2`:

```
ID Complete
1  Y
2  Y
3  N
```

But at the moment, it is not registering any as complete as the countif formula is returning a `0` for every row.

Is this because `countif` cannot handle dynamic ranges using `address`? If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it with a single formula:

```
={"ID","Complete";A2:A,index(ifna(if(regexmatch(vlookup(A2:A,
{A2:A,transpose(query(transpose(B2:D),,9^9))},2,),
"Complete"),"Y","N")))}
```

[image]

Here's another way you can do it with a dragdown formula:

```
=if(sum(filter(--(B$2:D="Complete"),A$2:A=F2)),"Y","N")
```

[image]